# A contatto o in contatto?

Tags: difference, prepositions

This sentence is in my coursebook: "Permette agli italiani di vivere una o due settimane **a contatto** con la natura e di riscoprire piaceri perduti della vita in campagna."
Is it the same as **in contatto**, because I can't find it in the dictionary? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2):

In this context no, I don't think there is any real difference. I find that **I** feel more comfortable using *a contatto* when referring to a physical contact (*stiamo a contatto* = we are touching) and *in contatto* when referring to a metaphorical one (*stiamo in contatto* = we hear from one another).

So *a contatto con la natura* conveys **to me** an idea of greater intimacy with Nature. But I have no official source for this, except my Tuscan origins :-)

You would use *a* if the "contact" is the means through which something works - e.g. *lenti a contatto*, *azione a contatto*, *interruttore a contatto*.

BTW -- I think it's a typo, but just in case, country is *campagna*, not *campagma*.

Comment: I think that 'a' is used with objects and 'in' with people. Easy.

Comment: However, [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/contatto/) gives these two examples of use of "contatto" meaning "relazione, rapporto" (that is, a relationship without physical contact): 1) *gli impiegati che sono **a contatto** col pubblico*; 2) *mettersi **in contatto** telefonico con qualcuno*.

Comment: @Nicholas: I'm not sure that's true because both the examples I reported from Treccani refer to people.

Comment: @Charo I didn't know what Treccani reports (perhaps is more correct than my opinion). Unfortunately, as native speaker sometimes I don't think about what I'm saying :D

Answer (score 0):

*in contatto* is used to describe relations between two or more human beings. *a contatto* is used to describe the relation with inanimate objects.

Edit:
*in contatto* is used in friendly context, or in a direct relation between two people. It is often used in colloquial dialogues and involves direct talking.
Ex: *teniamoci in contatto*, *rimaniamo in contatto*
*A contatto* is referred to objects or to indefinite groups of people. It is often used to describe in a non direct way, the role of a relation between people. Then, using this expression, the relation is always indefinite and doesn't specify that talking is involved.
Ex: "A contatto con il pubblico", "a contatto con il cliente"

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Alberto! I'm not sure that's true because both the examples I reported from Treccani dictionary in my comment refer to people.

Comment: Alberto, your examples look good, but for the general rule a source (grammar book, dictionary) would be appreciated.

Comment: I just wanted to explain how in the current Italian language is used, I studied grammar since I was a child, but obviously I'm not a book, I was hoping to be helpful! :)

Comment: Many of us are Italians and – to the best of my knowledge – none of us is a book, but an answer is better if it is supported by some source rather than just by one's “ear”.